# Server error 500 occurred when editing photo and text data using form data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, axios, react-hook-form

When a request is sent to the server to patch form data with photos and text data to modify user information, the server sends a 500 error.
And this is my code: Is there a problem with the code written by the client?

**UploadProfileImg File:**
This is my `UploadProfileImg` file. It displays the image that the user previously selected and, when the user edits the image, it shows a preview of the newly selected file in the circular space.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const UploadProfileImg = ({ setImageFile, currentImageUrl }: any) => {
  const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState<string | null>(currentImageUrl);
  const fileInputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPreviewImage(currentImageUrl);
  }, [currentImageUrl]);

  const handleImageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      setPreviewImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      setImageFile(file);
    }
  };

  const handleClickUploadArea = () => {
    if (fileInputRef.current) {
      fileInputRef.current.click();
    }
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      handleClickUploadArea();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      role="button"
      tabIndex={0}
      onClick={handleClickUploadArea}
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      style={{
        width: '60px',
        height: '60px',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
      }}
    >
      {previewImage && (
        <img src={previewImage} alt="Preview" style={{ width: '60px', height: '60px', borderRadius: '50%' }} />
      )}
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/jpeg"
        onChange={handleImageChange}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        ref={fileInputRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadProfileImg;
```

**EditUserProfile File:**
And this is my `EditUserProfile` file. Here, the user can edit their nickname, phone number, and address. After the user completes the modifications, the code sends the user's input and profile image to the server as FormData.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  MainContainer,
  PageTitle,
  RegisterInputWrapper,
  InputContainer,
  InputLabelStyle,
  InputStyle,
} from './RegisterPet';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Textarea from '@mui/joy/Textarea';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { IUser } from '../modules/userSlice';
import { getCookieValue } from 'hooks/getCookie';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';
import UploadProfileImg from '../components/UploadProfileImg';
import { useState } from 'react';

interface FormData {
  nickName: string;
  phone: string;
  address: string;
  body: string;
}

const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;

const EditUserProfile = () => {
  const { name, memberId, phone, address, email, nickName, body, petsitterBoolean, photo } = useSelector(
    (state: IUser) => state.login,
  );

  const [imageFile, setImageFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleImageFileChange = (file: File) => {
    setImageFile(file);
  };

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>();

  const onSubmit = async (requestbody: FormData) => {
    const token = getCookieValue('access_token');

    const formData = new FormData();
    if (imageFile) {
      formData.append('file', imageFile);
    }
    formData.append('requestBody', JSON.stringify(requestbody));
    console.log(requestbody);

    try {
      console.log(token);
      const response = await axios.patch(`${apiUrl}/members/${memberId}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.error(error.response.data);
        } else {
          console.error('AxiosError caught (no response):', error.message);
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Non-Axios error caught:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle>Edit Users</PageTitle>
      <UploadProfileImg setImageFile={handleImageFileChange} />
      <MainContainer>
        <InputContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="username">Name</InputLabelStyle>
            <Info>{name}</Info>
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabelStyle>
            <Info>{email}</Info>
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="nickName">Nickname</InputLabelStyle>
            <InputStyle type="text" defaultValue={nickName} {...register('nickName')} />
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="phone">Phone</InputLabelStyle>
            <InputStyle type="text" defaultValue={phone} {...register('phone')} />
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="address">Address</InputLabelStyle>
            <InputStyle type="text" defaultValue={address} {...register('address')} />
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <RegisterInputWrapper>
            <InputLabelStyle htmlFor="body">About me</InputLabelStyle>
            <Textarea
              minRows={3}
              sx={{
                width: '60%',
                borderColor: '#A6A6A6',
                borderRadius: '8px',
                fontSize: 14,
              }}
              defaultValue={body}
              {...register('body')}
            />
          </RegisterInputWrapper>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" sx={{ backgroundColor: '#279eff', mt: 5 }}>
            edit
          </Button>
        </InputContainer>
      </MainContainer>
    </>
  );
};

const Info = styled.div`
  ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.s14h21};
  width: 60%;
`;

const LinkContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
`;

export default EditUserProfile;
```

**Server API for Updating User Information:**
The server API is used to send a PATCH request when updating user information. Here's an example CURL request for updating a user's information:

```bash
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://localhost:8080/members/1' \
--form 'requestBody="{
    \"nickName\": \"kimcoding\",
    \"phone\": \"01011111111\",
    \"address\": \"06160 Seoul 415 1\",
    \"body\" : \"Hello, I'm coding Kim.\"
}";type=application/json' \
--form 'file=@"/D:/KITAE/Downloads/cat002.jpeg"'
```

The server expects data in FormData format. The changes are expected under the 'requestBody' key with a value like `{ "nickName": "kingcoding", "phone": "01011111111", "address": "06160 Seoul ]415 1st floor", "body" : "Hello, world!"`. If there are changes to the file, it can be sent using the 'file' key with the JPEG file attached.

Even if I send a patch request that removes modifications to the image file and modifies only the text first, the server 500 error continues to occur. I wonder if this is because there are also key and value properties in requestBody, or if it will be resolved by receiving values ​​with key values ​​for each item, nickName, phone, and address, rather than requestBody, when receiving data from the server like
{
"nickName": "member1",
"phone": "01011111111",
"address": "06160 Seoul 415",
}